# The number of real values for which set is Not a basis of $R^{2} $

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given set is $(a, a^{2}) , (a^{2} , a ) $ .

As i see that for a =1  ,0 and -1 set is not a basis .But how do i check it mathematically , if there are any other values ? Thanks

Comment: Do you know the what a determinant is?

Comment: After comupting determinant andequating to zero iget three valuesof a which i stated already.Is that it ?

Comment: Yes. That's it. The vectors are a basis if and only if the derminant is non-zero. So determining when exactly the determinant is 0 shows when exactly you have not a basis.

Answer (score 2):

A set consisting of two vectors in $\mathbb R^2$ is a basis  $\iff$ vectors are  linearly independent.

$c_1(a,a^2)+c_2(a^2,a)=0$

$\implies c_1a+c_2a^2=0;c_1a^2+c_2a=0$

Solve for $c_1,c_2$ we get $c_2a(a^2-1)=0$ if we assume $c_2\neq 0$ only possibilities for $a=0,1,-1 $solving for $c_1$ also yields same

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that the set {$ (a,a^2), (a^2,a)$} is a basis for $\mathbb R^2$ iff the determinant of the associated matrix is $0$, i.e., the set is a basis iff:

$$ a(a)-a^2(a^2)=a^2-a^4 \neq 0 $$.